# Where to find default android's google maps marker & default balloon code?

Tags: android, android-mapview

See the picture below. In my application (with MapView) usage, I would like to use such default markers (but with different background colors - red, green and yellow) and balloons. Where can I find these images & balloon code?

[image: google maps screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those should be in the Google Maps APK as ressource files. Since Google Maps is a proprietary app, you might not be allowed to use these. I recommend creating similar ones by yourself.

Answer (score 15):

In Eclipse: Window->OpenPerspective->DDMS. Go to FileExplorer tab, find the system->app->Maps.apk and click "Pull a file from the device"(small icon on top). Now, you can simple unzip this apk file(or just explore it with Total Comander) and get what you want in res folder.

Comment: Спасибо, Ghedeon. I'll try this.

Comment: +1 - Thanks, one small hint for windows users. After copying the .apk close the DDMS. Else you can't open the APK content.